# SQL Server : how to get 2 different query results with 1 single query using case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table I'm working on is a Employee log-in database. Amongst other things, it will be able to identify the time of entrance from an employee and to make a report on how his entrances have been during a set of dates.

The problem I am facing right now is: when the boss wants to see how a worker's log-in and log out work during a specific date. He wants to:

***a)*** set a date and a name, and for the query to return the accesses from that employee on that specific date.

***b)*** **IF he inputs no name**, then it will return a list with everyone for that date.

```
No | Name | ID  | Date       | Log-in | Log-out | Description
---+------+-----+------------+--------+---------+---------------------
1  | Joe1 | j1  | 2018/10/02 | 09:00  |  18:00  | Normal Exit
2  | Joe2 | j2  | 2018/10/02 | 10:00  |  17:00  | Meeting
.. | ...  | .   |   .  . .   |   . .  |   . . . | . . . . 
N  | JoeN | jN  | yyyy/mm/dd | hh/mm  |  hh/mm  | Whatever text
```

So for the first part I went with a simple

```
select * 
from DB
where @name = '*the name of the person to look for*' 
  and @date = '*specific date*' (is a date variable yyyy-mm-dd)
```

all done. Now the next part seems weird and have not been able to figure it out yet.

I was trying with an IIF scenario as a subquery but doesn't do the part where it returns the complete list.

Next is the where case but cant make it work either. I am missing a variable for the program to check:

if there is no name to look for => show table with everyone for that day

if there is a name to look for  => show table **ONLY** for that person

How can I make it so my program discriminates which table to show at the end?

Cheers!

EDIT:

ADDED (thanks for the recomendation) query for better assistance

```
CREATE TABLE DailyRegisters
(
     No          INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Name        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     ID          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Date        DATE  NOT NULL,
     Login       DATETIME  NOT NULL,
     Logout      DATETIME  NOT NULL,
     Description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO DailyRegisters (No, Name, ID, Date, Login, Logout, Description) 
VALUES (1,'Person 1','P1','10/2/2018','9:00','18:00','Normal'),
       (2,'Person 2','P2','10/2/2018','9:01','18:00','Normal'),
       (3,'Person 3','P3','10/2/2018','10:17','16:00','Plant'),
       (4,'Person 4','P4','10/2/2018','10:10','18:00','Normal'),
       (5,'Person 1','P1','10/3/2018','9:01','18:00','Normal'),
       (6,'Person 2','P2','10/3/2018','9:02','18:00','Normal'),
       (7,'Person 3','P3','10/3/2018','9:04','18:00','Normal'),
       (8,'Person 1','P1','10/4/2018','9:00','18:00','Normal'),
       (9,'Person 2','P2','10/4/2018','9:00','14:00','Meeting'),
       (10,'Person 3','P3','10/4/2018','9:17','18:00','Normal'),
       (11,'Person 4','P4','10/4/2018','9:00','18:00','Normal'),
       (12,'Person 1','P1','10/5/2018','9:00','18:00','Normal'),
       (13,'Person 3','P3','10/5/2018','9:00','20:00','Plant'),
       (14,'Person 4','P4','10/5/2018','9:00','18:00','Normal');
```

Comment: What's the table structure?

Comment: Hi, It's at the middle of the post. it has 7 columns: No, Name, ID, date, log-in, log-out, description. Is that what you mean by structure? Sorry I'm new to sql all together.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be really helpful if you could post ddl and sample data along with desired output. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great post on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, just edited. Tell me if something else is needed pls, (y)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to handle the case wherein no name is specified, like this:

```
select * from DB 
where 
    ((@name is not null AND name = @name) or (@name is null)) 
    AND date = @date;
```

Basically the above query will not check for name if the @name parameter is null. And of course it goes without saying that `@name` and `@date` are parameters passed to the query.

I also suggest not to use `select *` but instead specify the columns: It is better for maintenance in case your table schema changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That code unfortunately doesn't show the complete table when the name field is null. It shows "nothing" as a result but instead I need it to be as if all names for that date would appear.

Comment: Yep! that's the winner. Thank you so much. It actually is very 'Boolean' per se. Appreciate it.

Comment: `IsNull` or `Coalesce` can be useful here: use `name = coalesce(@name, name)` or `name = IsNull(@name, name)` (they are equivalent in this case) instead of the longer version above.